# Exclude using friendly_id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I want to run a controller query and exclude the current (self) record.  I can use this:

```
Model.where.not(slug: params[:id])
```

That works fine until you manage to pass the record id.

Is there a cleaner more direct way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I clarified my example.  I want to search where the id OR slug columns are not equal to the params[:id].  This also would have to chain after any normal scope or where query I run.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this query

```
Model.where('slug <> :param_id or id <> :param_id', {param_id: params[:id]})
```

Comment: I updated my question to clarify - I was not clear.

Comment: @DanTappin Updated my answer please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use [or](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or):

```rb
Model.where.not(slug: params[:id]).or(Model.where.not(id: params[:id]))
```

Or you can rewrite your query:

```rb
Model.where('slug <> :param_id or id <> :param_id', {param_id: params[:id]})
```